# Access info about a different job using curl command

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy

I am currently trying to access build information about jobA in jobB.  I was considering using:

```
$ curl "${JENKINS_URL}/job/${JOB_NAME}/lastSuccessfulBuild/consoleText"
```

but I have no Idea how I would be saving the console log. How would I be able to assign what I get from the curl statement to a variable that could be accessed by a groovy script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute it from the Groovy script for example?

```
def output = "curl ${JENKINS_URL}/job/${JOB_NAME}/lastSuccessfulBuild/consoleText".execute().text
```